# Query the Precision and Scale of a DECIMAL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, information-schema

I'd like to find the numeric_precision and numeric_scale of a column which is DECIMAL as a datatype.

I tried

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X'
```

But this only gives me "decimal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query system view `information_schema.columns`. I think that you are looking for columns `numeric_precision` and `numeric_scale`

```
select numeric_precision, numeric_scale
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and column_name = ?
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5334812795f82480a862b46249aabb94)**:

```
create table t (col decimal(10, 2));

select numeric_precision, numeric_scale
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'dbo' and table_name = 't' and column_name = 'col'
```

```
numeric_precision | numeric_scale
:---------------- | ------------:
10                |             2
```

Comment: @nimamandarine: I added a DB Fiddle that shows how to use the query, and that is producing the expected result. Please run the exact same query against your database, you should get the same result as I do in the fiddle...